# MongoDB PHP auth

Tags: php, authentication, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB. I started using it 2 months ago. I decided to test it for logs of one website (user behavior). At first without username and password. And it worked like a charm. I use RockMongo for admin. Then I created username and password and restarted the server. After the restart my script was unable to put data on database. However when I updated the settings of RockMongo it wirked and I can insert/update via RockMongo. I'm using MongoDB on Ubuntu 10 with PHP5. My code looks like
 this:

```
    $m = new Mongo();
    $db = $m->testlogs;
    $db->authenticate('username', 'password');
```

I cannot use shell too. When trying to authenticate I'm getting the
 following error:

"$err" : "unauthorized db:testlogs lock type:-1 client:127.0.0.1",
 "code" : 10057

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to connect to a specific database first. Just accessing $m->testlogs doesn't do that. Instead, you need to use as first line:

```
$m = new Mongo('mongodb://localhost/testlogs');
```

And optionally you could do:

```
$m = new Mongo('mongodb://username:password@localhost/testlogs');
```

Which allows you to drop the ->authenticate() call. The docs at http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.authenticate.php
also say:

> In general, you should use the authenticate built into
>   Mongo::__construct() in preference to this method. If you authenticate
>   on connection and the connection drops and reconnects during your
>   session, you'll be reauthenticated. If you manually authenticated
>   using this method and the connection drops, you'll have to call this
>   method again once you're reconnected.

Comment: This is now "legacy". Use the new driver. http://docs.php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php